# docker network macvlan driver not honoring driver_opts: MTU

Tags: docker, docker-network

According to https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/#connect-containers

driver_opts are:

```
com.docker.network.bridge.name  -   bridge name to be used when creating the Linux bridge
com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade  --ip-masq   Enable IP masquerading
com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc    --icc   Enable or disable inter container connectivity
com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4 --ip    Default IP when binding container ports
com.docker.network.driver.mtu   --mtu   Set the containers network MTU
```

I've changed the MTU of bridge driver by creating a network with a value to --mtu which works.

But the same option, --mtu, does not work if I change the driver to macvlan

Are the driver_opts different for macvlan? If so, what is its options to change MTU for macvlan driver for `docker network create`?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a long-standing bug in libnetwork: https://github.com/moby/libnetwork/issues/2274